# Jest unit test with React: App › encountered a declaration exception

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test my application made with React and I'm using Jest for tests, but I'm having difficulties in the first part, I'm trying to test App.jsx which is at the root of my application and I have the feedback:

**● App › encountered a declaration exception**

This is the app.test.jsx

```
import App from '../src/App';
import MyPage from '../src/pages/mypage';

describe('App', () => {
  const wrap = mount(<App />);

  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    shallow(<App />);
  });

  it('renders', () => {
    expect(wrap.find(App).exists()).toBe(true);
  });

  it('contains MyPage page', () => {
    expect(wrap.find(MyPage).exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

This is the App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { CssBaseline } from '@material-ui/core';
import { MyPage } from './pages/mypage';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <MyPage />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: app.test.jsx - import {MyPage }from '../src/pages/mypage';